# Forward declaration struct member access

Tags: c++, c, struct, definition

I have a forward declaration of a struct in `.h` file and full declaration of the same struct in `.c` file. I want to access it's members, but I get

> member access into incomplete type struct channel
> Here is my code:

**verbs.h**

```
struct channel;
```

**verbs.c**

```
struct channel{
    int index=10;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "verbs.h"
...
struct channel* ch;
...
ch->index;
```

verbs.h and verbs.c are legacy code, so I can't change them. Is there a way I can solve this problem?

Comment: `verbs.cpp` includes `verbs.h`, so it won't have any idea of what is in `verbs.c`...

Comment: @Yespa16 This declaration struct channel{
    int index=10;
}; is invalid in C.

Comment: Unrelated: You're not required to write `struct channel* ch;` in C++. Just write `channel* ch;`

Comment: *verbs.h and verbs.c are legacy code* -- Is this *all* the legacy code in those files, or your cut-down version of it?  If it is a cut-down version, please post the full code so that we have a better picture of what is actually in these files.

Comment: Perhaps the type is meant to be opaque and you've not supposed to poke around in it. I assume there's an API for working with these objects and perhaps a way to do what you want with that. Not enough information here for us to know or not.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is it valid in C++? As far as I remember `index` must be a `static const` to allow initialization.

Comment: It is odd that your `verbs.h` doesn't have include guards.  I believe this is not the entire file, and thus is not the entire picture of how to actually use the `struct` in a real-life program (maybe @RetiredNinja is correct).

Comment: @DavidRanieri It is valid in C++ at least starting from C++14 (or maybe even from C++11).

Comment: what is `verbs` ? Either it is made like this on purpose or it is broken. In either case you should reconsider what you are doing

Comment: Yes, those are not the entire files, it is cut-down. Sorry I can't post our entire source codes. Ask me what information do you need, I'll provide it if possible.

Comment: Since the definition isn't public verbs.cc has to export functions which can be used to perform tasks on the channel.

Comment: if you *really* don't have a better option, copy-paste the declaration from verbs.c into main.cpp. This is what #include does anyway.

Comment: Are you even supposed to use index in your C++ code? It looks like that member was "hidden" for a reason. Is there another "C" call that returns this pointer and the only thing you have to do is to hold on to it so you can pass it back later? At least that is what it looks like to me. (Kind of "private" members "C" style)

Comment: In this concrete case (since `index` is the first element of the `struct`), you can use `*(int *)ch;`

Comment: the information needed is why the author of `channel` made it so that you cannot access its members. Before looking for a workaround its better to first understand what you are working around.

Answer (score 2):

> so I can't change them
>
> Is there a way I can solve this problem?

Create `verbs2.h` with the *copied* content from `verbs.c`.

**verbs2.h**

```
struct channel{
    int index=10;
};
```

And just `#include "verbs2.h"`.

Comment: Good to say that this is a C23 feature: [Compatibility rules for structure, union, and enumerated types were changed to allow a redeclaration of a compatible type with the same tag.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)#Types)